# Document ID for List Items

Tags: list, custom-list, document-id

Is it possible to get a document ID for an item in a custom list?
I have the Document ID service enabled, but I can't see any document ID in the list of xsl items.

For reference, I'm using the following to list the XSL items:

```
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text> = </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Document ID` generated by `Doc ID service` is only for the documents available in the Document Library, and not for the list items.

When the service is enabled, a new column is automatically added to the `Document` and `Document Set` content types. The `Document ID` column displays the ID assigned to an item.

On the other hand the content type associated to items in a custom list is SharePoint's OOB `Item`. Thus `Document ID` will not be generated for items of a custom list.

Read this article on [Enable and configure unique Document IDs](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Enable-and-configure-unique-Document-IDs-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984)

Comment: I've read that article, but we're looking to use lists rather than documents for this data, as there's a standard format and things that need to be included

Comment: What is the purpose of the list. In future is it possible that items from that list is going to get transferred to another one?. Also what type of data you store in it?

Comment: @CyberJacob : Do you need a unique link and ID which targets to the list item?

Comment: yes, I do need a unique link. Items may get moved to an identical list on a different sub-site.

Comment: I am afraid `Doc ID service` will not be help full, you will have to apply some custom solution.